# How to know if an existing commit is already present in the workspace?

Tags: git, github, gerrit, repository

I have a git workspace an I want to know if a change has already been present in it..I think checking via commit is the best way wow to know if an existing commit is already present in the workspace?any other ideas you have to check if a change is already present inthe workspace is great too...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the commit have a change-id?  If so, I think the easiest answer is to use `git log | grep $CHANGE_ID`.  This will quickly let you know if that change-id is in your commit history.

The Gerrit web UI makes it easy to cherry-pick changes from the server to your workspace, so I can't think of a better approach using the original commit's SHA1.

Comment: if I do the above ,it doenst give me any details.the output is just what I grep for...may be the grep should be like show the 2 lines before and after?

Comment: Sure, you can do this with the -a2 -b2 flags.  If grep returns anything, the commit is in your workspace.  If it doesn't return anything at all, you are missing the commit.

Comment: `git log | grep -a2 -b2 $CHANGE_ID`.  Like I said, the few lines before and after aren't necessary - if grep returns anything at all than the change is in your workspace and if grep returns nothing than the change is missing.  To test, try using a bogus change ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if or how Gerrit actually fits into this, but you can examine a commit with

```
git show COMMIT
```

If it tells you it can't find the commit, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `git log` and grepping for the Change-Id is one way to do it, as mentioned in Brad's answer.  The downside of that is that you will pick up any references to that Change-Id in commit messages, and they may not be the actual change you're looking for.

Instead, you can search for the commit's sha1 like this:

`git log --format="%H" | grep 11111111222222223333333344444444`

Replace `11111111222222223333333344444444` with the sha1 of your commit.